# Are HTML tables somehow defined to sit at the bottom of a containing cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table, display

I was using the following tutorial to improve some of my layout and learn more about CSS display properties: https://www.sitepoint.com/solving-layout-problems-css-table-property/

The info seems straightforward enough and I tried to reorganize my layout in one particular `<section>` into one such wrapper, adding a Google Maps `<iframe>` in the middle section:

snip of my current webpage

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the HTML tables I'm using in the left and right CSS cells are sticking to the bottom, while the iframe is sticking to the top, and for the life of me I can't understand why.

I created a new page to test this out first by copying PRECISELY the code from the www.sitepoint.com tutorial. By default it worked exactly as the example did:

snip of exact code match

[image]

But when I wrap the paragraphs in HTML tables, the same behavior takes place:

snip of paragraphs wrapped in `<table>` structure

[image]

Is there something about `<table>` behavior that I don't understand? Why don't both of my tables lineup vertically with the `<iframe>`? Each of the three `<div>` have identical CSS:

```
.wrapper-cell {
display: table-cell;
width: 33.33%;
padding: 10px;
float: none;
}
```

None of it tells the data where to align vertically. I'm so utterly confused. Any clarity out there?

Comment: Right click and inspect and see what is wrapping what and how big it is

Comment: did you try setting `vertical-align: middle;` on the wrapping element?

Comment: Any chance you can post your full HTML and CSS so that we can reproduce the results in a browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for vertical-align is baseline. The baseline for your Contact and Location tables are, approximately and hand-wavy, the bottom of the first line of text in the first row. But the baseline for an iframe is (apparently) its bottom edge. Notice that the bottom of Contact, Location, and the iframe are aligned.

So change the vertical-align property on the table cells to something else, like top or bottom.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

And, yeah, as the other comments say, post your full HTML and CSS in the future.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the OP's doing, but you may be exactly wrong, In at least one plausible scenario, the solution is to change the table-cell vertical alignment *to* `baseline` from the user-agent imposed default styling of td elements of `middle`. Setting the vertical alignment to top or bottom does not work. See https://jsfiddle.net/mvdy2ums/1/

Comment: Hm, more nuanced than I thought. Didn't realize the default style sheet set has `td, th { vertical-align: middle; }`. 2 things. (1) In your example, the `#wrapper div` elements have `vertical-align:baseline` but their contents (the inner tables) are all pushed to the bottom. What are the baselines of those inner tables? Must be the bottom of their border box?

Comment: (2) I meant for OP to add `vertical-align:top` to `.wrapper-cell`, not to the inner `td`. OP must not have used `td` and instead have something like https://jsfiddle.net/dgrogan/mvdy2ums/2/. In which case https://jsfiddle.net/dgrogan/mvdy2ums/3/ seems to fix it.

Comment: The baseline of the inner tables is not, I think, the bottom of their border box, but the bottom content edge of the td. If the table had multiple rows and columns, it would be the bottom content edge of the lowest cell in the first row of the table. The actual bit of the CSS 2.2 spec says "If a row has no cell box aligned to its baseline, the baseline of that row is the bottom content edge of the lowest cell in the row." That's why setting the vertical-align to baseline works. The td becomes aligned to the baseline and that sentence no longer applies.

Comment: Thanks for the conversation, but it appears the original answer is indeed correct. Changing `.wrapper-cell` to `vertical-align: top` worked. I was indeed using full tables so definitely using `<td>`. The `.wrapper-cell` divs contain both tables and the `<iframe>` in the middle.